# Close Button Does Not Display in ui.bootstrap Alert

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, metronic

I am using ui.bootstrap alerts to display messages to users. However, the close button does not display. I'm developing an asp.Net application environment specifically in DNN. That's the only thing I can think of that could be causing the issue.

I have researched the following articles trying to find a fix:

[Close button not appearing for Bootstrap alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579865/close-button-not-appearing-for-bootstrap-alert)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.htm

I have tried manually providing the code for the button but that doesn't fix the issue.

My code:

```
<!-- START alerts -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible" uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in $ctrl.alerts track by $index" ng-class="'alert-' + (alert.type || 'warning')" close="$ctrl.closeAlert($index);" dismiss-on-timeout="5000">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;
                </button>
                {{ alert.msg }}
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- END alerts -->
```

The message displays and the alert is dismissable and will dismiss itself after 5 seconds as a workaround.

What I can see in the developer console is it's trying to pull a png file that doesn't exist. I can't even tell why it thinks this file would be there as the official bootstrap examples don't show the exact same CSS as I'm seeing in my environment.

```
// path it's looking for: WEBSITE/Portals/_default/Skins/MyTheme/assets/img/remove-icon-small.png
background-image: url(../img/remove-icon-small.png) !important;
```

Any thoughts on what I else I could try? Thanks in advance.

*Update: adding the missing png file to the location it's looking for it still does not cause the icon to display.*

Comment: wich version of ui.bootstrap you are using cause version 2.5.0 by default show the close button just simply `<div uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" ng-class="'alert-' + (alert.type || 'warning')" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</div>`

Comment: @JesusCarrasco Thanks for your input. I am using version 2.5.0.

Comment: are you using any bootstrap theme ? you could just override the template

Comment: @svarog I hadn't thought about having a theme. I'm using METRONIC by keenthemes. I can see that the close button does show in their examples. The CSS I noted in my post has the same quirk.

Comment: for a quick fix add a button with X and then use ng-click :P